# Most effifient way to update one column from 3 columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is this the most efficient way to update one single column from three different columns?

```
UPDATE TBL_FR2052A_TPOS_HIST_SPLIT
SET REPORTABLE_AMOUNT = ISNULL(PRINCIPAL,0)

UPDATE TBL_FR2052A_TPOS_HIST_SPLIT
SET REPORTABLE_AMOUNT = ISNULL(INTEREST,0)

UPDATE TBL_FR2052A_TPOS_HIST_SPLIT
SET REPORTABLE_AMOUNT = ISNULL(RAW_DATA_AMOUNT,0)
```

I am using SQL Server. Thanks!

Comment: why would you have to update it thrice? is it because of `null`s?

Comment: Yes, because of the nulls.  Based on certain IDs, Principal will be updated, or Interest will be updated, or Raw_Data_Amount will be updated.  It would be easier to work with, when everything is consolidated into one field.

Comment: Look again at your existing query. Only the last one has any useful effect - that update overwrites everything that the prior two did. So to answer your question based on your existing logic - just get rid of the first two statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try SQL : Case - When - End if you are checking Null for update fields.

Egs:

```
    UPDATE TBL_FR2052A_TPOS_HIST_SPLIT
    SET REPORTABLE_AMOUNT =
    case when ISNULL(PRINCIPAL,0) <> 0 then PRINCIPAL
    case when ISNULL(INTEREST,0) <> 0 then INTEREST
    case when ISNULL(RAW_DATA_AMOUNT,0) <> then RAW_DATA_AMOUNT
    else 0  --default value
    End
```

Regards

Abdul

Answer (score 5):

Looks like [COALESCE()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql) would help

```
UPDATE TBL_FR2052A_TPOS_HIST_SPLIT
SET REPORTABLE_AMOUNT = COALESCE(ROW_DATA_AMOUNT, INTEREST, PRINCIPAL, 0)
```

`REPORTABLE_AMOUNT` will then be updated with the first value in the `COALESCE()` that is not null.

Comment: The Coalesce did it!!  I was actually headed in that direction.  You beat me to it zambonee.  Thanks!!